# How to display more search results in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

By default it shows only 20 results. Unlike the main Google page, there doesn't seem to be a way to increase it to 100.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like that's not possible.

There is a setting at http://scholar.google.com/scholar_settings called **Results per page**, but it only offers 10 and 20. If you chose 20, it will add `&num=20` to your query string. You can reduce that value ([e.g to 5](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=something&num=5)) to get less results, but scholar does not seem to honour [values lager than 20](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=something&num=50).

Comment: Interesting. If Google indeed does not want you to be able to see more than 20 results on Scholar, I wonder what the reason for this might be.

Comment: It seems to me that Scholar is still just a toy project for Google. Maybe they just wanted to go easy on the server load a long time a go and never came back to change that limit. But that's just wild guessing.

Comment: Maybe they want to get more hits. Think that if 1000 results displayed on one page, only one hit needed, but 20 per page will need 50 hits, which could earn more money from advertisement. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips from [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_you_export_the_results_of_Google_Scholar_search_to_excel) and listed below:

The best was to use the Publish or Perish software (http://www.harzing.com/pop.htm). It cycles through the pages of a Google Scholar search results list and copies the basic information for each result to a results list that can be copied in CSV or Excel format.

The other method was to use Zotero (www.zotero.org) as an add-on to Firefox. You can use it to save the results on a single page of a Google Scholar results list (maximum 20 items). The drawback of this is that there doesn't seem to be a way to cycle automatically through the entire results list.

Other useful links include:

- http://www.searchenginejournal.com/export-google-search-results-to-excel/11253/
- http://www.marketing2oh.com/scrape-serps-for-seo-analysis/
- http://jurnsearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/how-to-extract-google-search-results-with-url-title-and-snippet-in-a-csv-file/